# Obtaining data from API and displaying it on page

Tags: javascript, json, api

I have simple idea:

1. Get geolocation from one API (http://ip-api.com/json) and display it
2. Base on this geolocation find (using another api http://api.geonames.org/) closest mountains within a radius of 70km
3. and display it names

I have a problem with third point - I get a link (displaying as alert) which leads me to the list of objects(?) in JSON format but ... I want an alert or html display with full list of mountains name. How to achieve this ?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">    
<head>    
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="api_try.css">    
    <script src="api_try.js"></script> 
</head>    
<body>
    <button type="submit" class="form-btn" value="sbutton" onsubmit="">Try!</button>

    <div id="geo_view">..</div>
    <div id="mountains">..</div>

</body>

</html>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(".form-btn").on("click", function () {    
            var lat;
            var lon;
            $.get("http://ip-api.com/json", function (data) {

                lat = data.lat;
                lon = data.lon;

                $('#geo_view').html(data.city);
                alert(data.city);
            });

            var url1 = "http://api.geonames.org/findNearbyJSON?lat=";
            var url2 = "&lng=";
            var url3 = "&featureCode=MTS&radius=70&username=zebru";

            var url = url1 + lat + url2 + lon + url3;

            alert(url);
            alert("2");

                $.get(url,function(data){
                alert("3");
                    var mt = $('#mountains").html(data.toponymName);
                   alert(mt);       
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: Is your issue getting the data or displaying it? If you are getting the data correctly, no need to include that in your question.

Comment: The jQuery `get` method is asynchronous which means that you have to move the rest of your code within its scope if you want to use the `lat`/`lon` variables.